# ASP.NET 4.5 authentication cookie is not persisted on Azure Web Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, authentication, cookies

I have problems with Forms Authentication on our Azure WebRole. It does not store the authentication cookie for the login. Once the user initiates a new session, he has to login again. 
First I tried:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userIdent, rememberMe);
```

Now doing it manually:

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userIdent, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6),rememberMe,string.Empty, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,encryptedTicket)
{
    Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
    HttpOnly = true
};
if (rememberMe)
{
    cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration; 
}
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Here a snippet from the web.config:

```
<machineKey decryption="Auto" decryptionKey="<My Decryption Key>" validation="SHA1" validationKey="<MyValidationKey>" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

But the problem remains. Sometimes it does remember it ?. Because it's running in an Azure WebRole, we added the MachineKey to web.config.

The problem might not be related to Azure Web Role, because we noticed the same behavior, running locally. Eg. localhost:7778